# Why i never get the correct exactly mouse cursor coordinates X and Y?

Tags: c#, winforms

In the main form i have this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (mf1 == null)
            {
                mf1 = new MagnifierForm(mConfiguration, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position);
                mf1.Show();
            }
        }
```

Then to see in real time the mouse position i added mouse move event:

```
private void CloudsAlertForm_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            label6.Text = e.X + " == " + e.Y;
        }
```

And this is the top of the form MagnifierForm:

```
public MagnifierForm(Configuration configuration, Point startPoint)
        {
```

Now the results:

When i put the mouse over the button before i click the button just put the mouse over it i see in label6: 134,547

Then on this line: mf1 = new MagnifierForm(mConfiguration, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position); on the Position i see each time i put the mouse over the Position with a breakpoint i see each time another coordinates .

And in the MagnifierForm top i see on Point startPoint 290,67

The question is what are the real mouse cursor coordinates and why each variable show something else ?

What i wanted to do is that when i click the button so the form MagnifierForm will get the exactly mouse cursor coordinates on the screen when i clicked the button ! Not the mouse cursor coordinates of the Form but on the screen !

Now im using a button but before it i used a global key hooking so i can activate the MagniferForm anywhere on the screen and i want to get the mouse coordinates cursor on screen !

I still dont get it why each time im getting a different coordinates on each variable ?

On the main form where i have the button click i also have a timer. The timer is running and do some stuff. When i click the button while the timer is  running i see the MagnifierForm on some x,y coordinates then i see it move like sliding to where my mouse cursor is now.
But if ther timer is not running when i click the button i see the magnifierform on the right exactly place where my mouse cursor is now !

Why when the timer is running i see the MagnifierForm sliding/moving from a certain place to where the cursor is ?

Comment: When you use a breakpoint your mouse cursor is still being updated even though your program is stopped when you use Cursor.Position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple.

`Cursor.Position` gives you the mouse co-ordinates relative to the screen. Whereas `MouseEventArgs` gives you the co-ordinates relative to the control that you are handling the click event on.